# "current-page:title" when adding a node

Tags: tokens, files

I have a node-type with an image field. while uploading a file I would like to put it in a node-specific directory which is named after the node title. 
while using tokens, there is no `node->title`, while I am creating the node, so the `current-page:title` is the `node->type` I am trying to add.
so this works only when adding files to an existing node.

my solution-idea:

1. should I restrict adding files before the node is already created? the node should be created unpublished.

are there other solutions / a shorter way e.g. a two-step-edit-form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need [FileField Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths). See [ImageField Tokens](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_tokens) for tokens in default values for alt and title attributes as well.

Comment: should be proposed to the 8.0 version.

Comment: just post to the issue queue ;) See http://drupal.org/node/73179 and http://drupal.org/node/10262